# how to use the tryparse method to assign the value in a text box control to a variable

Tags: vb6

I have a text box named hours, I need to grab the value entered bu the user in the hour text box and assign it to variable int h using tryperse method.

In addition i have a boolean variable isConvrted which is true if tryperse rertuned a value, and false if it did not.

I have tried alot of codes but non seem to work.

currently  i have

if TryPerse(hours.text, isConverted) Then
.
.
.
 Else
.
.
.
endif

By the way I am running Visual studios 6.0 Enteprise.

Please tell me what to do.
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify.  "Visual studios 6.0" is VB6 not VB.NET.

Comment: I don't think there's a TryParse in vb6, if you are using .net then look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, your code sample use TryPerse which shouldn't compile. What do you mean by "non seem to work"? What is the error you are having?

Comment: Yea, it's actually vb6.

I have tried
If int32.TryPerse(hours.Text, isConverted) Then
.
.
.
Else
.
.
.
End If

The error I'm getting is "Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: that is because VB6 does not have an `Int32` neither a `TryPerse` nor `TryParse` function unless you wrote one.

Comment: Thank you for that bit of info.